# Como apresentar um número em typescript com uma formatação específica?

Tags: typescript

Eu possuo uma propriedade `montante` no objeto abaixo, e estou apresentando na função `escreverNaTela()`:

```
class Objeto{

  constructor(private montante: number){}

  escreverNaTela(){
    let mensagem = 'R$ ' + this.montante;
    console.log(mensagem);
  }
}
```

Porém, ao escrever na tela, se o valor de `montante` for um número inteiro o valor não vai aparecer com as duas casas decimais após a vírgula, como de costume. Como eu posso converter a string desse valor `montante` para que tenha essas 2 casas decimais após a vírgula?

Comment: Mas não é só utilizar toLocaleString() ?

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo o indicado por @LeAndrade, eu utilizei o método [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```
escreverNaTela(){
  let mensagem = this.montante.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {style: 'currency',currency: 'BRL'});
  console.log(mensagem);
}
```

Caso seja necessário , é possível utilizar a opção `minimumFractionDigits`:

```
escreverNaTela(){
    let mensagem = this.montante.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2});
    console.log(mensagem);
}
```